# Run .sh every time a file changes

Tags: server, virtualization

I'm working with a system that uses a Ubuntu server as base but we do program at Windows. The VMs are using the Mount command to have access to the files at Windows.

Everytime someone saves a file, that person needs to get to the server and rerun the command to get ERP server down and up again.

Since we do not change the files a lot(a team of 2 or 3 are working on a few files), there is any way to trigger a script every time a file gets changed?

Workflow:
Programmer saves file >> Windows update file at ERP folder >> Linux instance who has the windows folder mounted gets the update >> Linux executes .sh who reruns the server.

Comment: This question should be in SuperUser, where there's a few answers to your question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes).

Comment: This problem can also be solved using **Upstart**, which is born in Ubuntu, and therefore is Ubuntu-related.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is using inotifywait from the package "inotify-tools".

For examples see the best answer in https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/) tool, e.g.

```
$ ls -d * | entr sh -c 'make && make test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours.
I'm developing a program on tornado and I have to restart server on each commit so I just wrote a program on bash that closes all python processes and starts it again

```
#!/bin/bash
function init {
    LIST=`pgrep python`
    IFS=' ' read -a arr <<< "${LIST}"
    for pid in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        echo $pid
        `kill -9 $pid`
    done
}
init
IN=`python server.py`&

CONTENT=`cat server.py`
while :
do
    sleep 1
    CURR=`cat server.py`
    if [ "$CONTENT" != "$CURR" ]; 
        then 
            init
            IN=`python server.py`&
            CONTENT=`cat server.py`

            echo "Restarted."
        fi;
done
```

Script runs like a daemon, when file is changed it just restarts the server.

Maybe it isn't the best solution but it works.

Comment: If you're using git to commit your files, you could simplify this action by using it as a hook (post-commit) rather than a daemon running all the time.